# Set Alarm without DateTime and TimePicker in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set alarm without datetime picker and time picker. It always shows invalid time. Here is my code

```
public void setClockTimeScheduler(Context ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+2, 00);

            if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
             //The set Date/Time already passed
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Invalid Date/Time"+cal.compareTo(current)+"Or"+current, 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    setAlarmScheduler(cal,ctx);
                }
```

Comment: what you act want to do...cant understand

Comment: I am adding current time +2 minutes and setting alarm. so every after 2 minutes there will be some event triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that you are running this code with the right parameters? Because I have tried your code and it worked for me (I mean I never get into the "Invalid Date/Time" block). I did some modification:

```
    public void setClockTimeScheduler(Context ctx){
        Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, current.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+2);
        if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
            //The set Date/Time already passed
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Invalid Date/Time" + cal.compareTo(current) + "Or" + current);
        }else{
//            setAlarmScheduler(cal, ctx);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please implement it with date time and try to compare. I didnt understand  this code cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,current.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+2);

Comment: It's the same as you did : "cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+2, 00);" just doasn't reset the seconds ;)

Comment: i am still getting invalid toast

Comment: Than please share your code where you call this method and also the setAlarmScheduler function!

Comment: thanks my colleague understood your code and it worked.. thanks a lot. i have ticked your answer. i dnt have 15 repo.

Comment: I hope it really helped, because I have changed the Toast to Log, so if you got the message in toast before you will see it in the LogCat now.... :/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are adding two minutes in current time. if condition cannot be true at any cost. if statement is useless remove it and used the code below It will surely help you!

```
    public void setClockTimeScheduler(Context ctx){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,2);
     setAlarmScheduler(cal, ctx);
    }
```